# What pattern should I use to replace zeros and ones as exponents?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to *replace* certain values using `regex` in a **binomial** expression to replace the values equivalent to a determined *constant* `x` that has as exponent the numbers `1` and `0`, example: `binomial = "625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x^1+81x^0"`.

This is the pattern i am using: `r'[a-z][^][0]'`

but it is not returning the desired value `"625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x+81"`.

What pattern should I use to replace `'x^1'` and `'x^0'` with an empty or **null** character like `''`?

Comment: Surely the desired value is `"625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x+81"` (note 540**x**)?

Comment: You could replace `x^0` and then `^` with empty string. Or `^` first and then `x0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
x\^([01])\b
```

which will match `x^` followed by `0` or `1`, and replace using a replacer function that will return `x` if the exponent is `1`, otherwise nothing:

```py
binomial = "625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x^1+81x^0"
res = re.sub(r'x\^([01])\b', lambda m:'x' if m.group(1) == '1' else '', binomial)
```

Output:

```
625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x+81
```

Comment: unlike the answer from user @Daaran I see that you use a shorter pattern and a `lambda` function so "intuitively" I would say that your answer is the most efficient.

Comment: Previous version doesn't work for exponents >= 10, since the "1" incorrectly gets matched; fixed now

Comment: @ellhe-blaster hard to say. Certainly my regex is easier to match (it's about 7x more effcient according to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/KBU3MU/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/QtNeC7/1), but there is the cost of a function call to make the replacement. Assuming you're not doing this a lot I think you wouldn't notice any real difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions, `^` is a [special character](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/) which matches either the start of the line or it can be used to exclude a group. If you want to match a literal `^` character you will need to escape it with a `\`. Additionally, `\` is a special character in python strings so you need to either add 'r' to the start or use `\\`.

This should work (run the code snippet to demo the Python):

```js
import re

binomial = "625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x^1+81x^0"
pattern = r'[a-z]\^[01]'
s = re.sub(pattern, "", binomial)
print(f"{s=}")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

p.s. It is unclear from the question whether you want to do math to evaluate the string or not. If you do that will require a more complex regular expression with a replacer function. I would go through a [tutorial](https://regexone.com/) and play around with regular expressions [here](https://regex101.com/)

```js
import re

binomial = "625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x^1+81x^0"
pattern = r'([a-z])\^(\d*)'

x = 2
scope = locals()

def replacer(match):
    var_name, pow = match.groups()
    pow = int(pow)
    r = eval(f"{var_name}**{pow}", scope)
    print(f"{var_name} ** {pow} = {r}")
    return f'*{r}'

s = re.sub(pattern, replacer, binomial)
s
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for exponents >= 10, since the "1" incorrectly gets matched.

Comment: @craigb I'm well aware of that but this matches the desired output in the question listed above.... Maybe they are trying to do math on the string but that's not actually what the question asks so I'm not assuming that

Comment: the objective of the program in general is to multiply bionomials with an exponent, receiving the formula in text as input.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually want to keep the x in x^1 therefore we can use this expression with a lookbehind assertion which will not be part of the match.

```py
binomial = "625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x^1+81x^0"

print(re.sub(r"[a-z]\^0|(?<=[a-z])\^1\b", "", binomial))
# Output 
625x^4+1500x^3+1350x^2+540x+81
```

---

`[^...]` is a `not in` ... expression ^ needs to be escaped.